# Scroll Vertically inside ListView when ListView is VerticalAlignment="Stretch"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scroll

How do we get the `ListView` to behave properly? I am trying to scroll vertically inside my `ListView`, and I was eventually able to get something to scroll vertically, but the `ListView` keeps expanding in height! and setting `MaxHeight` doesn't do anything.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="ActivityLog" Margin="0, 201, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView x:Name="ActivityList" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5" TextAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
```

I am at a loss. Please help. How do I get the listview to just scroll vertically only, and never change in height, and never display the horizontal scrollbars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `StackPanel`. That prevents the `ListView` (or any other children) to have a delimited size. That's why you're not getting any scrollbars, because the `ListView` has an infinite height, as layout-ed by the StackPanel.

Besides, having a `StackPanel` with only 1 child makes no sense. It's supposed to "stack" its children.

Edit: Also remove the `ScrollViewer`, as the `ListView` already has a `ScrollViewer` inside of it as per the default Template. Unless of course you had changed the Default `ControlTemplate` for that.

Comment: Thank you HighCore. I did originally plan on adding more to that StackPanel but I got lazy.